# How can I dock my winform application with another application

Tags: c#, winforms, docking

I am trying to do my winform application dock and follow another application, like IE or word. My full plan is run the program underground and then this specific application is running, my winform will maximize and dock, will follow if moved, minimize if this application is minimized.

Can you guys show me some ideas about how to do it?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will have to get the messages send to the other application and analyze them. Here are some resources on window system hooks on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589(VS.85).aspx) and in the [MSDN Magazin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188966.aspx). So you will have to use good old P/Invoke because there is no managed API.

Answer (score 0):

Hooks can work; however, both the programs you mention (IE & Word) provide APIs that allow you to customize the user interface.  I would first look there.  BTW, Due to IE's restricted environment your going to have a lot of trouble getting the standard hook APIs to work.